# Alternative to: normals_make_consistent ops (is too slow)

Tags: python

I try to make bmesh method but not have idea about in the apy not find that method, i need to adjust faces orientation for object selected, but my script is too slow...
I try :

```
selected =  bpy.context.selected_objects

for o in selected:

    if o.type == 'MESH':

        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')                        
        bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='SELECT')
        bpy.ops.mesh.normals_make_consistent(inside=True)                       
        bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='DESELECT')
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
```

Edit 2:

```
    meshes = set(o.data for o in context.selected_objects if o.type == 'MESH')
    bm = bmesh.new()

    for m in meshes:
        bm.from_mesh(m)          
        bmesh.ops.recalc_face_normals(bm,faces = bm.faces)
        bm.to_mesh(m)
        m.update()
        bm.clear()
    bm.free()
```

From Api blender , this method adjust orientation inside, but not find api to orient outside

Edit 3:

i find a bmesh ops

```
bmesh.ops.reverse_faces(bm,faces = (bm.faces), flip_multires = True)
```

now i control that in an if statement after the recalc_face_normals

Comment: Show your bmesh code, please. Others can then improve it, even if it isn't working

Comment: @Leander Ty , but no have idea about bmesh Api, because i know other function in bmesh no idea about  to normals_make_consistent in bmesh method